# 'Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character' on heroku deploy

Tags: angularjs

I wrote an angular app using yeoman generator. It works great in development, but after I deploy to heroku and visit a specific page I get this error:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [\] in expression [\].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20nextharacter%20&p1=s%200-0%20%5B%5C%5D&p2=%5C
    at http://ang-news.herokuapp.com/scripts/244c37f5.vendor.js:3:30474
    at Zd.throwError (http://ang-news.herokuapp.com/scripts/244c37f5.vendor.js:6:14396)
    at Zd.lex (http://ang-news.herokuapp.com/scripts/244c37f5.vendor.js:6:13696)
    at $d.parse (http://ang-news.herokuapp.com/scripts/244c37f5.vendor.js:6:16445)
    at http://ang-news.herokuapp.com/scripts/244c37f5.vendor.js:5:13197
    at e.parseAs (http://ang-news.herokuapp.com/scripts/244c37f5.vendor.js:5:23401)
    at Object.e.(anonymous function) [as parseAsResourceUrl] (http://ang-news.herokuapp.com/scripts/244c37f5.vendor.js:5:23604)
    at http://ang-news.herokuapp.com/scripts/244c37f5.vendor.js:6:28873
    at q (http://ang-news.herokuapp.com/scripts/244c37f5.vendor.js:4:23046)
    at h (http://ang-news.herokuapp.com/scripts/244c37f5.vendor.js:4:19250)
```

[This description](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected) says the error occurs when an expression has a lexical error.

What's that and why is it only showing up in production?

Comment: did you deploy all script file to server?

Comment: In my case it was a ” instead of a "

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had some error while I 
used **ng-click**

```
<a ng-click="#/search/San+Francisco">test</a>
```

instead of **ng-href**

```
<a ng-href="#/search/San+Francisco">test</a>
```

I hope it might help

Answer (score 24):

If you are using ng-pattern='/some_reg_ex/'. Please save it in some scope variable, say `$scope.emailPattern = '/email_regex/'`

Comment: For me quoting regular expression in double quotes worked as shown:  
    `$scope.emailPattern = "email_regex_expression"`

Answer (score 20):

In general, this occurs when **you supply a string literal when angular is expecting an expression or function**. A "#" in the string causes the `$parse:lexerr` error.

In my case, I was setting a string literal to a custom directive attribute, when I should have been using an expression.

**Incorrect**:

```
<my-directive my-attr="/foo#bar"></my-directive>
```

**Correct**:

```
<my-directive my-attr="'/foo#bar'"></my-directive>
```

In this example, the `my-attr` attribute was set for two-way binding (=) in the custom `my-directive`. If it was set to "@" the error would not have occurred.

```
scope: {
  my-attr: "="
}
```

Answer (score 16):

In my case this was caused by the regular expression not being enclosed by `/`, ie. `ng-pattern="^[0-9]$"` instead of `ng-pattern="/^[0-9]$/"`.

Comment: Consider this scenario, I want to pass a regex into a directive that in turn uses ng-pattern in the template. So, I pass the regex without the delimiters like **pattern="^[abc]$"** and I use *@* for the attribute and in the template, I use **ng-pattern={{pattern}}**. I get the Lex error on the console but the regex works. Any idea how to get rid of the console error?

Comment: Enclose the regex in single quotes like this: "'^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$'". This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

@russenreaktor is right, but more specifically, this error will occur when you use incorrect syntax.  For me, I had accidentally misplaced the `$` character, used in angular, with `#`, used in handlebars:

```
<button class="danger" type="button" title="Remove Property Asset {{#index}}">Remove Asset</button>
```

Of course, fixing the `#` character resolved my issue:

```
<button class="danger" type="button" title="Remove Property Asset {{$index}}">Remove Asset</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with ng-click.

```
ng-click="#"
```

I just deleted it and the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

Parameter passed as string is not a valid literal string:

```
ng-init('[aa]')
```

instead of

```
ng-init([aa])
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case was a ng-show having a #

Bad:

```
<a ng-show='#'>
```

Best.

Answer (score 1):

When my model value `surveyCtrl.user.googleEmail` is `someone@gmail.com`, I got this error when using:

```
ng-disabled="{{surveyCtrl.user.googleEmail}}"
```

The condition works:

```
ng-disabled="{{surveyCtrl.user.googleEmail != ''}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while using select options with ng-value so, I just kept value instead of the ng-value attribute.

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="employee in employees"
            title="{{employee.fullName}}"
            value="{{employee.email}}">
       {{employee.email}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the error using something like

```
<div ng-bind="{{vm.myModel}}"></div>
```

fixed it by removing mustaches :

```
<div ng-bind="vm.myModel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get Lexer errors when working with International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA) characters. Angular can't handle ɨ, ʉ, ɯ, ɪ, ʏ, ʊ, etc. HTML can handle these, for example, ʊ is `&#650;`. But Angular (or maybe TypeScript?) won't allow `myFunction_ʊ` etc.